# Problems with varying sized form fields

Tags: php, html

I'm not sure how to make this work. We have to build a CSV file using PHP. The forms used to create the CSV file are the subject of this problem. The program deals with make / model / year.

page 1 asks the question: 'how many makes do you want'
page 2 asks the question: 'how many models per make'

This is what I have so far:
index.php:

```
<form action="import_page_1.php" method="post">
Number of Makes: <input type="text" name="num_makes" value="Enter a number"></input><hr>
<input type="submit" value="Next.." />

import_page_1.php:

<form action="import_page_2.php" method="post" />
<?php
$num_makes = (int) $_POST['num_makes'];
$count = 0;
$make_array = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_makes; $i++) {
        $count++;
        echo "Make $count: <input type='text' name='$make_array['make'] /><br />";
}
?>
<hr>
    <input type="submit" value="Next.." />
</form>
```

I don't know how to make $make_array populate each thing the user enters. I can't just specity ['make'] like I did in my example because then all I get is the last result.

So maybe I'm going about this the wrong way or maybe this is some easy solution to create a form based on the number of fields given previously and then create an array based on makes such as 'Toyota' or whatever. My test case was 1: Nissan, 2: Toyota. On the next page all I got out of my $_POST array was the last one entered "Toyota" I assume because it is overwriting each 'make' in the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I am not English speaker so I am really sorry if something is not clear but I will try my best.

Ok if I understood your problem what you need to do is an array of inputs to get all the values in the next page.

Right now I know a couple of methos, I will tell you what I consider the easy one, it is to give diferent names to each input in the (for()) loop like this:

```
<?php
<form action="import_page_1.php" method="post">
Number of Makes: <input type="text" name="num_makes" value="Enter a number"></input><hr>
<input type="submit" value="Next.." />

import_page_1.php:

<form action="import_page_2.php" method="post" />
<?php
$num_makes = (int) $_POST['num_makes'];
        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_makes; $i++) {
            echo 'Make '.($i+1).': <input type="text" name="new_input"'.$i.' /><br />';
    }

?>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $num_makes?>" name="total_new_inputs"/>
```

Then in the next page you can get the values by using another loop (for()) to re-construct the input names written before, like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $_POST['total_new_inputs']; $i++) {
        $value.$i = $_POST['new_input'.$i];
        echo $value.$i;

}
```

I hope you got it all.